# Hazelcast Add Local Entry Listener Only Once

Tags: hazelcast, spring-session

I have a 3-node application that includes an embedded Hazelcast instance (so, 3 instances). These are used in the application for session sharing across the nodes. In the configuration, I added a local entry listener to write an audit record to the database.

Unfortunately, this caused something of a race condition because the listener ended up being added to the internal map of listeners 3 times. I'd end up getting a "connection has already been closed". I ended up switching to an interceptor which did NOT seem to get added multiple times.

I don't consider the interceptor method to be a great solution. However, the `addLocalEntryListener()` method returns a random UUID. So, it's not a matter of determining if the key exists in the map.

Ideally, I'd like something like this:

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance instance() {

    HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.getInstance();
    
    IMap<String, ?> sessionsMap = instance.getMap("spring:session:sessions");

    if (/* something something to ensure the listener wasn't already there */) {
       sessionsMap.addLocalEntryListener(new MyLocalListener());
    }

}
```

Comment: Local listener is ... local :-). You need to add it on each node.

Comment: Doesn't that @Bean method get called exactly once on each node ? If so you could add the local listener there unconditionally.

Comment: You'd think so, right? I eventually had to switch over to an interceptor and write code to check what partition the item being removed from manually. It was bull, but it worked.